# PHP+MS Access: Wildcard * being taken as a string when querying through PHP?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, wildcard

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE test_5 SET test_5.[it/technical] ='tech' where test_5.[Application URL] like '*' & 'App' & '*'; (to update all Application URLs containing 'App')
```

When ran :

- **directly in Microsoft Access**: It works correctly & updates all the records with `Application URL` containing word APP, i.e. Applications etc. are updated
- ***as a query through PHP***: The wildcard `*` is taken simply as a part of the string, not a wildcard, thus it matches only `*App*`(read it `starAppstar`);

Help me asap...

Stuck at it since last two days...

Regards,
Viral

Comment: @Balanivash: You were correct too...
It was just dat... I didn't get u...
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to read at the following link, it seems that * is not the right operator for like in MS ACCESS.........

http://forums.devarticles.com/microsoft-access-development-49/like-operator-not-working-with-ms-access-sql-queries-1992.html

Another useful link:

http://www.mycsharpcorner.com/Post.aspx?postID=43

See also this:

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=110190

this is the google query i've written to find the previous hyperlinks:

http://www.google.it/#sclient=psy&hl=it&source=hp&q=like+%2Bms+%2Baccess+%2Bphp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=bb1f5215b4cfdc3a&biw=1280&bih=598

Comment: The wildcard depends on the interface you're using. In native Access with default settings the wildcards are `*` and `?`. In native Access with ANSI 92 mode turned on, the wildcards are `%` and `_`. DAO uses ANSI 89 wildcards (`*`/`?`) and OLEDB/ADO uses the ANSI 92 ones (`%`/`_`).

Answer (score 2):

In SQL `%` is the wildcard. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: Boss,
I'm using MS-Access DB, so gotta use * there instead.

Comment: See comment above -- which wildcards are involved depends on the interface you're using to communicate with Jet/ACE.